# How do you create an F# workflow that enables something like single-stepping?

Tags: f#, workflow, computation-expression

I'd like to create a builder that builds expressions that returns something like a continuation after each step.

Something like this:

```
module TwoSteps = 
  let x = stepwise {
    let! y = "foo"
    printfn "got: %A" y
    let! z = y + "bar"
    printfn "got: %A" z
    return z
  }

  printfn "two steps"
  let a = x()
  printfn "something inbetween"
  let b = a()
```

Where the 'let a' line returns something containing the rest of the expressions to be evaluated later on.

Doing this with a separate type for each number of steps is straightforward but of course not particularly useful:

```
type Stepwise() =
  let bnd (v: 'a) rest = fun () -> rest v
  let rtn v = fun () -> Some v
  member x.Bind(v, rest) = 
    bnd v rest
  member x.Return v = rtn v

let stepwise = Stepwise()

module TwoSteps = 
  let x = stepwise {
    let! y = "foo"
    printfn "got: %A" y
    let! z = y + "bar"
    printfn "got: %A" z
    return z
  }

  printfn "two steps"
  let a = x()
  printfn "something inbetween"
  let b = a()

module ThreeSteps = 
  let x = stepwise {
    let! y = "foo"
    printfn "got: %A" y
    let! z = y + "bar"
    printfn "got: %A" z
    let! z' = z + "third"
    printfn "got: %A" z'
    return z
  }

  printfn "three steps"
  let a = x()
  printfn "something inbetween"
  let b = a()
  printfn "something inbetween"
  let c = b()
```

And the results are what I'm looking for:

```
two steps
got: "foo"
something inbetween
got: "foobar"
three steps
got: "foo"
something inbetween
got: "foobar"
something inbetween
got: "foobarthird"
```

But I can't figure out what the general case of this would be.

What I'd like is to be able to feed events into this workflow, so you could write something like:

```
let someHandler = Stepwise<someMergedEventStream>() {
  let! touchLocation = swallowEverythingUntilYouGetATouch()
  startSomeSound()
  let! nextTouchLocation = swallowEverythingUntilYouGetATouch()
  stopSomeSound()
}
```

And have events trigger a move to the next step in the workflow.  (In particular, I want to play with this sort of thing in MonoTouch - F# on the iPhone.  Passing around objc selectors drives me insane.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem with your implementation is that it returns "unit -> 'a" for each call to Bind, so you'll get a different type of result for different number of steps (in general, this is a suspicious definition of monad/computation expression).

A correct solution should be to use some other type, which can represent a computation with arbitrary number of steps. You'll also need to distinguish between two types of steps - some steps just evaluate next step of the computation and some steps return a result (via the `return` keyword). I'll use a type `seq<option<'a>>`. This is a lazy sequence, so reading the next element will evaluate the next step of the computation. The sequence will contain `None` values with the exception of the last value, which will be `Some(value)`, representing the result returned using `return`.

Another suspicious thing in your implementation is a non-standard type of `Bind` member. The fact that your bind takes a value as the first parameter means that your code looks a bit simpler (you can write `let! a = 1`) however, you cannot compose stepwise computation. You may want to be able to write:

```
let foo() = stepwise { 
  return 1; }
let bar() = stepwise { 
  let! a = foo()
  return a + 10 }
```

The type I described above will allow you to write this as well. Once you have the type, you just need to follow the type signature of `Bind` and `Return` in the implementation and you'll get this:

```
type Stepwise() = 
  member x.Bind(v:seq<option<_>>, rest:(_ -> seq<option<_>>)) = seq {
    let en = v.GetEnumerator()
    let nextVal() = 
      if en.MoveNext() then en.Current
      else failwith "Unexpected end!" 
    let last = ref (nextVal())
    while Option.isNone !last do
      // yield None for each step of the source 'stepwise' computation
      yield None
      last := next()
    // yield one more None for this step
    yield None      
    // run the rest of the computation
    yield! rest (Option.get !last) }
  member x.Return v = seq { 
    // single-step computation that yields the result
    yield Some(v) }

let stepwise = Stepwise() 
// simple function for creating single-step computations
let one v = stepwise.Return(v)
```

Now, let's look at using the type:

```
let oneStep = stepwise {
  // NOTE: we need to explicitly create single-step 
  // computations when we call the let! binder
  let! y = one( "foo" ) 
  printfn "got: %A" y 
  return y + "bar" } 

let threeSteps = stepwise { 
  let! x = oneStep // compose computations :-)
  printfn "got: %A" x 
  let! y = one( x + "third" )
  printfn "got: %A" y
  return "returning " + y }
```

If you want to run the computation step-by-step, you can simply iterate over the returned sequence, for example using the F# `for` keyword. The following also prints the index of the step:

```
for step, idx in Seq.zip threeSteps [ 1 .. 10] do
  printf "STEP %d: " idx
  match step with
  | None _ -> ()
  | Some(v) -> printfn "Final result: %s" v
```

Hope this helps!

PS: I found this problem very interesting! Would you mind if I addapted my answer into a blog post for my blog (http://tomasp.net/blog)? Thanks!

Comment: Just an addition, this is also very similar to the so-called Resumption monad. But I believe the implementation with sequences could be a bit easier to use in F#.

Comment: "PS: I found this problem very interesting! Would you mind if I addapted my answer into a blog post for my blog (http://tomasp.net/blog)?"

Of course, feel free.  Thanks for the answer; I'm looking at it now trying to figure out how to fit it into the iPhone event system.

Answer (score 1):

Monads and computation builders confuse the hell out of me, but I've adapted something I've made in an [earlier SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779859/f-storing-and-mapping-a-list-of-functions/1781904#1781904). Maybe some bits and pieces can be of use.

The code below contains an action queue, and a form where the Click event listens to the next action available in the action queue. The code below is an example with 4 actions in succession. Execute it in FSI and start clicking the form.

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Windows.Forms

type ActionQueue(actions: (System.EventArgs -> unit) list) =
    let actions = new Queue<System.EventArgs -> unit>(actions) //'a contains event properties
    with
        member hq.Add(action: System.EventArgs -> unit) = 
           actions.Enqueue(action)
        member hq.NextAction = 
            if actions.Count=0 
                then fun _ -> ()
                else actions.Dequeue()

//test code
let frm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form()

let myActions = [
    fun (e:System.EventArgs) -> printfn "You clicked with %A" (e :?> MouseEventArgs).Button
    fun _ -> printfn "Stop clicking me!!"
    fun _ -> printfn "I mean it!"
    fun _ -> printfn "I'll stop talking to you now."
    ]

let aq = new ActionQueue(myActions)

frm.Click.Add(fun e -> aq.NextAction e)

//frm.Click now executes the 4 actions in myActions in order and then does nothing on further clicks
frm.Show()
```

You can click the form 4 times and then nothing happens with further clicks.
Now execute the following code, and the form will respond two more times:

```
let moreActions = [
    fun _ -> printfn "Ok, I'll talk to you again. Just don't click anymore, ever!"
    fun _ -> printfn "That's it. I'm done with you."
    ]

moreActions |> List.iter (aq.Add)
```

Comment: In a way, what I'm trying to get is something that uses workflows to build what you're doing by hand.  The workflow would generate a sequence of functions and then you'd just iterate through the sequence.